# Jinja templates parse text twice in Airflow

Tags: airflow, jinja2

I have a DAG that requests SQL script via REST API and executes it.

```
SimpleHttpOperator(
    task_id='get_sql_query',
    endpoint='path/to/sql_file.sql',
    method='GET',
    http_conn_id='some_http_conn_id',
    log_response=True
) >> SQLCheckOperator(
    task_id='check_something',
    sql='{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="get_sql_query") }}',
    params={"table_name": "test_table"}
    conn_id ='postgres_default',
)
```

Here is the code of `sql_file.sql`:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1) == COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM
    {{ params.table_name }}
```

Right now it doesn't parse `table_name` and tries to execute literally `{{ params.table_name }}`.

But, I want to set this `table_name` inside my DAG. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I realized on my end both with and without quotes around the Jinja template in the SQL file works. And yes, the SQL code fetched from an upstream operator does not get templated but there is a workaround:

```py
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.providers.common.sql.operators.sql import SQLCheckOperator
from pendulum import datetime


@dag(
    start_date=datetime(2023,2,2),
    schedule=None,
    catchup=False,
)
def testing():

    @task # replace this with your SimpleHTTP operator
    def fetch_sql_query():
        return """SELECT
                COUNT(DISTINCT id) > 1
                FROM
                {table_name}"""
    
    @task # have a task in the middle that fills in the templates
    def create_sql(query, table_name):
        return query.format(table_name=table_name)

    t2 = SQLCheckOperator(
        task_id='check_something',
        sql="{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='create_sql') }}",
        conn_id ='postgres_default',
    )

    create_sql(fetch_sql_query(), "ab_permission") >> t2
testing()
```